# Javascript package manager inside the browser

Tags: javascript, package, bower

I'd really like a package manager like Bower etc that I can just call from javascript in a browser to load a javascript package from the web and use it right away.  Right now I'm just trying to use Jsdelivr, which unfortunately has no real api and lacks necessary integration conventions.

Is there any existing way to do this?

Comment: not sure if what you want exists...but cdnjs keeps all packages available in http://cdnjs.com/packages.json I used it to build a script/link tag creator tool on my local machine for  starting wireframe pages. I currently write it to local json with php so I can use it in a single page app for quick search and setting tags up with current url's, create favorites etc

Comment: API is coming soon https://github.com/jsdelivr/jsdelivr/issues/196
Feel free to contribute and tell me what you need exactly.